# Save preferences in one Activity and use in another

Tags: android, android-preferences

The problem is that I save the settings in one Activiti

```
final CheckBox semester=(CheckBox)layout.findViewById(R.id.chbSemeseter);
Context context = getApplicationContext();
final SharedPreferences preferences =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
final SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
final Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(layout);
builder.setTitle("Select current week and semester!");
builder.setPositiveButton("First Week",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        if (semester.isChecked()){
            int week=calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
            editor.putInt(APP_PREFERENCES_SEMESTER,week);
            editor.putInt(APP_PREFERENCES_SEMESTER,1);
            editor.commit();
        } else {
            int week=calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
            editor.putInt(APP_PREFERENCES_SEMESTER,week);
            editor.putInt(APP_PREFERENCES_SEMESTER,2);
            editor.commit();
        }
    }
});
```

But when I tried use them in another activity I get error

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
if (preferences.contains(ActivitySetting.APP_PREFERENCES_WEEK)){
    String t=preferences.getInt(ActivitySetting.APP_PREFERENCES_WEEK,0)+"";


    MyLog.d("Now week "+t);
}else {
    MyLog.d("NOt preferences");
}
```

error logs:

```
//Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:240)
        at com.example.Journal.UI.ActivityLiveDiscipline.onCreate
```

How can I save preferences in one Activity and use in another?

Comment: could you please show the line which stores APP_PREFERENCES_WEEK in preferences?

Comment: public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_WEEK = "week";

Comment: This is just a declaration. You have never saved it anywhere.

Comment: I Did not understand what should I do. I just want to save information once in one Activity and get in another every time. Do you have any tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you set the APP_PREFERENCES_SEMESTER setting but you read the APP_PREFERENCES_WEEK one. You should use the same name.

Answer (score 0):

you are use **same key for different integer value** so **make different key like below**

```
builder.setPositiveButton("First Week",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            if (semester.isChecked()){
                                int week=calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
                                editor.putInt(APP_PREFERENCES_SEMESTER_WEEK,week);
                                editor.putInt(APP_PREFERENCES_SEMESTER,1);
                                editor.commit();
                            } else {
                                int week=calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
                                editor.putInt(APP_PREFERENCES_SEMESTER_WEEK,week);
                                editor.putInt(APP_PREFERENCES_SEMESTER,2);
                                editor.commit();
                                }
                        }
                    });
```

in another Activity use:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
int intweek = preferences.getInt(APP_PREFERENCES_SEMESTER_WEEK, 0);
int intextra = preferences.getInt(APP_PREFERENCES_SEMESTER, 0);
```

one more thing do not need to do this:

```
if (preferences.contains(ActivitySetting.APP_PREFERENCES_WEEK))
```

because if Prefrance is not set then its give you 0.

Comment: In place int week I get same error Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:240)
        at com.example.Journal.UI.ActivityLiveDiscipline.onCreate

Comment: can you show me line number 240 in SharedPreferencesImpl.java

Comment: no, I get error when I tried get preferences in this case  int intweek = preferences.getInt(APP_PREFERENCES_SEMESTER_WEEK, 0);

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=+java.lang.ClassCastException:+java.lang.Boolean+cannot+be+cast+to+java.lang.Integer&oq=+java.lang.ClassCastException:+java.lang.Boolean+cannot+be+cast+to+java.lang.Integer&gs_l=hp.3...1278.1278.0.1527.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c.1.12.psy-ab.eOPKbNQob0k&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45960087,d.bmk&fp=102d4945c0f75701&biw=1366&bih=664